# How to connect ReactJS with Backend like Mysql

Tags: mysql, reactjs, api, express

I am new to reactJS...

I am familiar with python-django.. now i wanna create backend for my react app.

used react for just front end purpose.. is their a way to communicate my react frontend with react own backend?

I am using **MySQL** Database.. is their any better way to create **API** in **react Backend**? 
i knew this connection part alone,

```
var mysql_conn = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql_conn.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect()

connection.query('SELECT _data AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution)
})

connection.end()
```

any suggestion ? shall i use any framework like `expressJS` with `React`?

Comment: For initial page loading,one can use . server rendering but for rest you have create and use API rest or any typical get/post

Comment: React is a frontend (view) framework and does not provide any backend. You can use it on the backend for server side rendering, but apart from that it has nothing to do with your backend. You should expose your backend data through some kind of API and for that express or [koa](https://github.com/koajs/koa) would work fine.